# error: -bash: grunt: command not found

Tags: macos, gruntjs

bit of a macosx noob , trying to install grunt on my machine. I tried:

```
npm install grunt
```

It look like the files are downloaded properly but still getting the error.
When I do echo $PATH it does not look that the path is pointing to grunt. Do I have to install it from a certain directory? How can I fix this?

Edit
After I run :

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

This happens:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`, then you can use `grunt` in your terminal

Comment: yes I tried that too still getting the same error,thnks

Comment: Are you sure you used the `-g` option? What is the output of your `npm install -g grunt-cli` ?

Comment: I added some more info see above

Comment: it responds with the same output (see image above) and it does not recognise the grunt command.